# Branch IO Deep Linking works only after I clear the Safari history and cache data on iOS

Tags: deep-linking, branch.io

I'm trying to add a sharing feature to my existing app using Unity Branch SDK.
I retrieve custom data from `initSession` function of Branch SDK (Unity).

```
void Start()
{
    Branch.initSession(CallbackWithBranchUniversalObject);
}

void CallbackWithBranchUniversalObject(BranchUniversalObject buo,
                                    BranchLinkProperties linkProps,
                                    string error)
{
    string senderDeviceID = linkProps.controlParams["$deviceID"];
}
```

`initSession` function seems to work a few times but it returns empty `BranchUniversalObject` JSON and `BranchLinkProperties` JSON after that. After a few days of struggling, I found that Safari history and cache data causes the issue. When I clear the Safari history and cache data, `initSession` function works again as I expected and I can retrieve custom data from Branch deep link.

How do Safari history and cache data affect the Branch deep link?
What should I do to fix the problem of empty `BranchUniversalObject` JSON and `BranchLinkProperties` JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling and reinstalling the app several times often results in browser cache not refreshing as per the App's current state.
Please check on the AASA file for the current state on the device as well : https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/ios-troubleshooting#section-validate-if-aasa-file-successfully-downloaded

A possible solution here :

1. Uninstall app
2. Clear browser cache
3. Restart device
4. Reinstall App

You can submit your query [here](https://help.branch.io/using-branch/page/submit-a-ticket) as well.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer! Is there any other option to solve this problem?
I'm going to add a dummy query at the end of branch short URL. It results in disregard of the browser cache. Do you think the dummy query will be another solution?